# Two Jetty embedded Server instances in one process

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

My question is simple: is it perfectly safe to have 2 independent Jetty [`Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) instances in one JVM process, listening on different ports with independent URL mappings and SSL/TLS setup? I'm not seeing odd behaviour but before deploying to live, I'd like to get some assurance that what I'm doing is sound. If not, would it be proper to have the same set-up using a single [`Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) instance with somehow separate URL namespaces and security SSL/TLS setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  We do this in many unit tests throughout Jetty.